# Cannot getText Because of wrong Id

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while but seems not to work. I am getting a nullPointer Exception on this Line `school.setClasses(classesName.getText().toString());`in the code block below.

Which is the code that actually posts to the SQLite Database

```
 public void postSchoolSetuptoSQLite() {

        school.setSchoolName(nameOfSchool.getText().toString());
        school.setSchoolLocation(schoolLocation.getText().toString());
        school.setClasses(classesName.getText().toString());
        academeaSQL.addSchool(school);

        if (demeaSQL != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (School s : demeaSQL.getAllSchools()) {
                sb.append(" SchoolName= " + s.getSchoolName() + " SchoolLocation= " + s.getSchoolLocation()
                        + " ClassName= " + s.getClasses());
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            Log.i("Database content", sb.toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Log.i("Database Err", "Database Error");
        }



    }
```

I am creating the field for the classesName dynamically by clicking an "Add New Class" Button through this onAddField Method

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);

        rowView.setId(ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId());


        // Add the new row before the add field button.
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

        Log.i("ids", String.valueOf(rowView.getId()));
    }
```

The field Id is dynamically generated through the ViewIdGenerator Class.

The Error is at this point  `classesName = rowView.findViewById(rowView.getId());`  when getting the Ids from the dynamically created fields in this code block

```
public void findByIds() {

        rowView = new View(this);

        parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);

        nameOfSchool = findViewById(R.id.nameOfSchool);

        schoolLocation = findViewById(R.id.schoolLocation);

        addSchoolAndMoveNext = findViewById(R.id.addSchoolAndMoveNext);


            classesName = rowView.findViewById(rowView.getId());

            Log.i("Classname", String.valueOf(classesName));
            Log.i("SchoolLoca", String.valueOf(schoolLocation));

    }
```

Here is where I am calling the `findByIds();`

```
 @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_search_setup);

        findByIds();
        intitializeListeners();
        initializeObjects();





    }
```

For the Nullpointer exception. the error is pointing at these areas

```
school.setClasses(classesName.getText().toString());
```

and

```
classesName = rowView.findViewById(rowView.getId());
```

Please why am I getting the nullpointer exception and How can I resolve it. Thank you. I will really appreciate your responses.

Comment: where/when are you calling `findByIds()`?

Comment: You stated the error is in two different places... which one is it?  Also NullPointerExceptions are very easy to solve especially with the debugger.  You wouldn't need our help if master this powerful tool.

Comment: try to implement something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017297/how-to-get-id-of-multiple-edittext-dynamically-added

Comment: ok @Rafa thank you for your response I really appreciate it same with you  I am calling the findByIds on the default oncreate method. Lemme edit the question to show the call.

Comment: @Sam here the errors are in the Lines 'school.setClasses(classesName.getText().toString());'  and 'classesName = rowView.findViewById(rowView.getId());' I will edit my question to make this clear

Comment: if you are calling `findByIds()` inside of `onCreate()` then `rowView.getId()` will return null, because you are setting the id in the default id generator AFTER the button gets pressed. `onCreate()` gets called when the activity first starts up.

Comment: Ok @Rafa I understand your point and that exactly is what happened when I was testing it through  LogCat but I did not interpret the problem this way,.Thanks for that. so what do you suggest as possible solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like every time you press the button you are trying to create a layout and add all of the class names. Is that right?

Comment: @Rafa Exactly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if you are calling `findByIds()` inside of `onCreate()` then `rowView.getId()` will return null, because you are setting the id in the default id generator AFTER the button gets pressed. `onCreate()` gets called when the activity first starts up.

It also looks like you are trying to add a list of classes when you hit the button. There are built in ways to do this in Android that have a bit more overhead than what you are doing (in terms of time it takes to implement) but that are going to be much more reliable for scrolling, adding new classes, deleting classes, etc.

Look into the [recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) in order to do this

Inside of the Display Cursor contents in a RecyclerView section [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/creating-sqlite-databases-in-your-app-719366/) will show you how to add data from the database to the RecyclerView

Comment: ok. Noted. But each school class is added one at a time eachtime the button is clicked, does the recycle view take care of this as well?

Comment: I've edited my answer and linked to a handy resource that has an example on how to do that. If you have more questions about the specific implementation if you get stuck, please open another question with the specifics :)

Comment: New questions wont be possible form me anymore as I have been blocked for asking further. Meanwhile, Thank you so much for your time, you were really helpful and I appreciate that.

Comment: Sorry to hear :( I think accepting answers helps with that since it means that ask answerable questions.